# Instance attribute mutability (very basic)

Tags: python, object, instance, mutable

**Immutable object with two names bound to it:**

```
xint=1
yint=xint
print yint #>>1
xint=2
print yint #>>1 - did not change as expected since yint refers to an immutable object
```

**Mutable object with two names bound to it:**

```
xmutable=[1,2,3]
ymutable=xmutable
print ymutable #>>[1,2,3]
xmutable[2]='yo'
print ymutable #>>[1,2,'yo'] - changed since the list object referred to was mutated, as expected
```

**Name bound to instance attribute that mutates:**

```
class bob:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n=n
        self.i=0

bob1=bob(2)

i = bob1.i
print i #>>0
bob1.i += 1
print i #>>0 - did not change, not what I expected.
```

So above, and forgive me if this is a really dumb question, I view the global name `i` as referring to an instance attribute `bob1.i` (and not the underlying integer), which should be mutable.  I would expect that similar to when a name is bound to a list, that if the list mutates (or instance attribute in this case) all names bound to it would reflect that change (like the second example).

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is, but `i` does _not_ hold a reference to `bob1.i`, because it's of an immutable type (int). There is no `instance attribute` object or anything like that.

Comment: So then instance attributes are just more names that refer to the actual underlying objects?  Does this basically mean then that the name `i` is just a reference to another name `bob1.i`, that is a reference to an integer?  I was under the mistaken impression that instance attributes were objects themselves and not just another name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ints are immutable so i is pointing to the int value of bob.i, when you use `bob.i += 1` that creates a new object. If you were using a mutable item like a list then the values would change for i and bob.i as they would still both be pointing to the same object:

```
class bob:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n=n
        self.i=[0]

bob1=bob(2)

i = bob1.i
print i #>>0
bob1.i[0] += 1
print(bob1.i)
print i #>> now both are [1]
```

using your code if you print the id's you will see i always points to the same object but bob.i points to a new object that is created with bob.i += 1:

```
class bob:
    def __init__(self, n):
        self.n=n
        self.i=0

bob1=bob(2)

print(id(i))
print(id(bob1.i))
bob1.i += 1
print(id(bob1.i))
print(id(i))
print(id(1))
28426608
28426608
28426584
28426608
```

Comment: I suspected `i` was referring to an integer otherwise that behavior wouldn't make sense.  So basically my mistake was thinking that bob.i was an object itself when in fact it's just another name that is bound to objects.  So in my example, `i` is a name that refers to `bob.i` that is just another name that refers to an integer.  Is that correct?

Comment: @Solaxun, yes, a way to cheat a little is try printing `print(id(1))`, python caches some small ints so you can see that indeed the id is for the int object.